# Exporting to QField from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qfield

In creating an export from QGIS 3.8.0 Zanzibar to Qfield using the sync plugin, I am encountering a strange error.

Each time I run the export, several of the layers I have in a geopackage in QGIS file do not correctly copy over to the newly created *_qfield.qgs file.

The odd thing is that I can't systematically reproduce the error; each time I test the export, I have different layers that successfully export or fail. There are ten layers in the geopackage.

Does anyone have thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

I am pretty new to QField.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error and was able to fix it by changing the export folder from our Linux-based server to a local folder on my Windows desktop. Apparently the system makes a difference. Haven't encountered the error since I started doing it like this.